# Javamail unread message returns very last messages rather than unread

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Here is my code, it should be getting unread messages. However it is returning the very last messages in my inbox. Any suggestions?

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.search.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore;

public class MailClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.setProperty("mail.pop3.connectionpooltimeout", "3000");
      props.setProperty("mail.pop3.connectiontimeout", "3000");
      props.setProperty("mail.pop3.timeout", "3000");

      Session session;

          URLName url = new URLName("pop3","pop.gmail.com",995,"","email@gmail.com","pwd");
    session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session,url);
    store.connect();

    Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
    FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen,false);
    Message message[] = folder.search(unseenFlagTerm); 

    for (int i=0, n = message.length;i<20;i++) {
        System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
                    System.out.println("From : " + message[i].getFrom()[0]);
                    System.out.println("Subject : " + message[i].getSubject());
                    System.out.println("Sent Date : " + message[i].getSentDate());
    }
    folder.close(false);
    store.close();
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may be up against the limitations of POP3 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POP3 protocol doesn't support any flags, so it can't tell you whether a message has been read or not.  See the [javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package for more information](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use as follows and give it a try;

```
int messageCount =  folder.getUnreadMessageCount();

if(messageCount>0){
 Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, it outputted the same thing. I wonder what is going on. All these normal solutions are not changing anything..

Comment: when you say very last messages, does it mean the last unread message? are you trying to read messages that just arrived in your inbox or ones that you have set as unread by using the flag?

Comment: I am trying to read unread messages in my inbox. By very last I mean the absolute oldest messages in the inbox.

Comment: In your loop, what is the variable "n" there? as far as i see you are looping the first 20 records that you find in your mail box.

Comment: Right, otherwise I'd get 525+ emails and would have to wait for that script to stop. And I wouldn't see recent emails until the 500th.